# TFS undo pending changes

Tags: tfs

I have little question, we have an project and I have made some changes in one file and I need to undo those changes ( I have not checked them ) and I need to get the latest version. If I will go for "Undo pending changes" it will only change my files and will not change TFS files right ?

Answer (score 1):

Yup. Changes are only local until you commit them in tfs.